# how do I get multiple cron jobs to run?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to run three commands every x amount of time written in a crontab that is in turn executed on my server. I've tested each one individually in the terminal and they all work. I've also checked "pgrep cron" and the crontab is apparently running. I think my problem is writing the crontab correctly. Can someone tell me if there's something wrong with my cron?

```
*/1 * * * * command
*/5 * * * * command
*/5 * * * * command
[newline]
```

Comment: Is it the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`) or your own crontab (you edit it with `crontab -e`)? The system crontab has an extra column: the user used to run the command, between the time columns and the command column.

Comment: The time commands you've added are fine so likely it's an access or command problem. Keep in mind that when cron runs a task, there's no cwd

Comment: @axiac It's my own crontab.

Comment: @DaveK when you say access do you mean the allow and deny files? Because I have those. Also, my cron used to work when there was only one  command. I have also tried the individual commands to verify they work.

Comment: I mean access to the directory and files by the user running the cronjob, which I guess is the user you're logged in as.

Trying the command at the prompt isn't the same as cron running the command as there is no CWD. For any scripts I run under cron, I always have a bash script going to the directory the script needs to be run from then I run it.

Comment: @DaveK I see what you mean, but even with the bash script starting out with 'cd $HOME' cron won't run it. Again, I can successfully run the bash from the terminal but as you pointed out that may not tell me anything. So I think I'm down to figuring out the user portion. Is there a way I can specify a user in a crontab?

Comment: crontab -u [username] -e